# Space between bottom of page and row at a certain position

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive website. Everything works well, except when you resize it to one particular point. At this point, there is a space between the bottom of the page and the last content that I have on that page (a row of four images). I have looked at similar solutions online, but they don't seem to work for me. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Website is at https://www.metallicpalette.com/.
Code is at https://github.com/arjunsingla/metallicpalette

Comment: have a look at [css3 @media rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: @Redanium he is currently using media queries

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

try this one always bottom of your screen.

Comment: This prevents the site from being fully responsive